# Installing Django on Jython

Tags: django, installation, jython

I am trying to install Django with Jython.

System - Windows 7, 64bit
Jython - 2.5.4rc1 (installed succesfully)
Django - 1.5 (not yet installed)

When I am in the unpacked Django-1.5 directory and try to run the command line instruction

'jython setup.py install'

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "setup.py", line 84, in (module)  
    version = __import__('django').get_version()  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\bin\Django-1.5\django\__init__.py", line 6, in get_version  
    from django.utils.version import get_version  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\bin\Django-1.5\django\utils\version.py", line 1  
SyntaxError: future feature unicode_literals is not defined
```

I can imagine that it is something very simple that only an ABSOLUTE NEWBIE could ever get wrong. So we all know what I am :)

Many thanks for any help in taking my first wobbly steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django 1.5 has dropped support for Python 2.5. Therefore, you have to use a Jython 2.7 alpha release if you want to use Django 1.5 with Jython. Please use Django 1.4 if you want to keep using Django on a stable Jython version.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/

Comment: Ahh yes, I thought it was going to be very obvious and simple. I read that section on the website several times but somehow it didn't register with me properly. Django 1.4.5. installed perfectly, many thanks.